# Is there a way to delete particular content of a group?

Tags: python, pygame, pycharm

How do you remove content from  a pygame sprite group?

I have tried:
    del self.game.treasures

I didn't really think of another way to do it.

```
if pg.sprite.spritecollideany(self, self.game.treasures):
    del self.game.treasures
```

I just expected it to delete the group, but an error happened:

```
if pg.sprite.spritecollideany(self, self.game.treasures):
AttributeError: 'Game' object has no attribute 'treasures'
```

Comment: Can you please add a bit more code, where is `self.game.treasures` defined & used?

Comment: treasures is a sprite group in the code defined in the Game class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to delete a [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) object and you want to delete it from all [`pygame.sprite.Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group)s, then you've to use [`pygame.sprite.Sprite.kill`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite.kill):

> ```
> kill()
> ```
>
> The Sprite is removed from all the Groups that contain it. This won't change anything about the state of the Sprite. It is possible to continue to use the Sprite after this method has been called, including adding it to Groups.

e.g.

```py
mysprite.kill()
```

If you want to remove all sprites from a group, then you've to use [`pygame.sprite.Group.empty`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.empty):

> ```
> empty()
> ```
>
> Removes all Sprites from this Group.

e.g.

```
myspritegroup.empty()
```

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way kill one member of the group if they're all named the same thing? Also is there a way to collide with the player using pygame.sprite.spritecollideany?

Comment: @jaden.joeyak - Add a `sprite.name`, fill it when you create the sprite, and them put them all in a dictionary `all_sprites` at construction time.  Then later on, when you want to remove "enemy01", you can do `all_sprites["ememy01"].kill()`